# Private vs Registered vs SAP domains in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, sender-authentication-package, sap

As the title suggests, can you explain the difference in terms of possible sending or deliverability issues?

So for me say my company's SAP domain is **@mail.companyname.com**, but the emails they want to send from are marked as a registered domain in the from address management section as just **@company.com**. Is there an issue using the registered domain for sends and not the one marked as SAP?

Also is there any sending or deliverability issues with using any text before the @ when sending emails i.e. **product@company.com** or **orders@company.com**

Let me know what you think.

Comment: Please remember to mark my answer as accepted if it has been helpful

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send from x@company.com, while having mail.companyname.com as your SAP domain, there are few things to observe. This is doable, but you must also purchase Private Domain SKU (in addition to SAP SKU)

- SAP domain is **mail.companyname.com**. This makes bounce domain *bounce.mail.companyname.com*
  (needs to be in same domain as corporate domain for DMARC compliance)
  Click domain will be *click.mail.companyname.com*, etc.
- Private Domain should be **company.com**
  This Private Domain DNS will be custom and client hosted. You need to reach out to support to get the right DNS settings, and implement only the DKIM-related DNS entries.
  Don’t implement Salesforce MX record for the private domain or it will break your corporate mail! You can now disable RMM, so that replies go directly back to corporate employees. Provide dedicated IP info to support, so this private domain will send from the SAP IP address.

Also, since your SAP domain is under a different domain than your private domain, the DMARC will fail, as both should be under the same domain (i.e. your SAP domain should be mail.company.com). In order to overcome this, you should ask support to enable “multi-bounce domain” feature, when adding your new private domain, to ensure your private domain will comply with DMARC.

Also, username (part before **@**) does not have any impact on deliverability, as long it comes with an authenticated email domain (SAP or Private Domain)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So all things said, is it safe to say the simplest route would be to suggest stop using the registered domain @company.com and switch the SAP @mail.company.com? I don't think they'll have strong feelings on the switch if it means overall better security/performance etc.

Comment: Indeed. Utilising only single SAP domain as the sender domain will be the simplest and easiest solution